# How to change the "Unselected Item Tint Color" in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, xcode8

I would like to have the selected item in the bar to be white, and the unselected items to be a light gray. I have searched and came upon many answers but none have worked for me. I have tried using user defined runtime attributes, just changing the tint color in attributes inspector, and adding the following code to my `TabViewController`:

```
[self.tabBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.tabBar setUnselectedItemTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

I have the selected item white as I want it to be, but I can not figure out how to do the unselected item color.

I am currently running XCode 8.3.3 with a deployment target set for iOS 9.3.

[image: Here is a screenshot of my tab:]

Comment: setUnselectedItemTintColor is available for ios10 or later,

Comment: I had a feeling that would be the problem... I dropped the build version so I can run it on an old iPad because it was all I had available. This worked... thank you!